# Running future n times

Tags: scala, nonblocking, future

I'd like to run my future call n times, for example 5. Future "execution" will take some time and I want to call new one only when previous was completed. Something like:

```
def fun(times: Int): Future[AnyRef] = {
   def _fun(times: Int) = {
      createFuture()
   }

    (1 to times).foldLeft(_fun)((a,b) => {
      println(s"Fun: $b of $times")
      a.flatMap(_ => _fun)
    })
}
```

So I want to call "_fun" function n times one by one. "createFuture()" will take some time, so "_fun" shouldn't be called again before previous future was completed. Also, I want to create a non-blocking solution. Currently, this code executes without waiting for previous future to end.

Any ideas how to make it work?

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: What do you want your return type to represent?  Does it need to somehow aggregate the results of the chained future calls?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without understanding what exactly you want the final future to return (I'm going to just return the result of the last completed future), you could try something like this:

```
def fun(times: Int): Future[AnyRef] = {
  val prom = Promise[AnyRef]()
  def _fun(t: Int) {

    val fut = createFuture()  
    fut onComplete {
      case Failure(ex) => prom.failure(ex)
      case Success(result) if t >= times => prom.success(result)
      case Success(result) => _fun(t + 1)
    }

  }
  _fun(1)

  prom.future
}
```

This is a sort of recursive solution that will chain the futures together on completion, stopping the chaining when the max number of times has been reached.  This code is not perfect, but certainly conveys one possible solution for making sure the successive futures do not fire until the previous future completed successfully.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to specify that I wanted to return last future or sequence of them, not so important actually. Your solution works as I expected, thanks. This will work great for temp solution, will think later about making it prettier :)

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be nicer if you make it recursive using flatMap.

Let's imagine you have your createFuture defined as:

```
def createFuture() = Future( println("Create future"))
```

We can create a function to compose the result of createFuture with:

```
   def compose(f: () => Future[Unit])(b: Future[Unit]) = b.flatMap(_ => f())
```

And then you can define fun as:

```
 def fun(n : Int) = {
     def nTimes(n : Int, f : Future[Unit] => Future[Unit], acc : Future[Unit]) = if (n == 0) acc else nTimes(n-1,f,f(acc))
     nTimes(n,compose(createFuture),Future())
 }
```